# Scala - Play: how to nicely handle WS get exception

Tags: web-services, scala, http, playframework

I have this function which uses [Play WS services](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaWS):

```
def executeRequest(urls: List[Url]): List[Future[String]] = 
  urls.map(url => {
      WS.url(url.url).get().map(x => url.url + ": " + x.statusText )
  })
```

Where `Url` is a case class so defined:

```
case class Url(id: Long, url: String)
```

I want my application to be resilient and sometimes the `url` value triggers an `IllegalArgumentException` if the url is not well formed. What I tried was this:

```
def executeRequest2(urls: List[Url]): List[Future[String]] =
  urls.map(url => {
    WS.url(url.url).get().map(x => url.url + ": " + x.statusText )
    .recover({
      case e: IllegalArgumentException => url.url + " is invalid"
    })
  })
```

This doesn't work, most probably because the exception is thrown inside the `.get()` and not inside the future execution (it's just a guess anyway).

What I ended up doing is this:

```
def executeRequest(urls: List[Url]): List[Future[String]] =
  urls.map(url => {
    try {
      WS.url(url.url).get().map(x => x.statusText)
    }
    catch {
      case e: IllegalArgumentException => future {
        url.url + " is illegal."
      }
    }
  })
```

This works, but I would like some nicer and more idiomatic way to handle this exception. Note that here I haven't added the `recover` to handle eventual problems inside the future execution which will make this piece of code even more illegible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Try` is your friend here.

```
import scala.util.Try

urls.map(url => 
    Try(WS.url(url.url).get().map(x => x.statusText))
        .getOrElse(Future.successful(url.url + " is illegal."))
)
```

This will replace all exceptions with the error message in the `getOrElse`. We can be a little more fine grained than that though. Perhaps we could keep the invalid URLs as successful `Future[String]`s, but convert all others to failed `Future`s.

```
urls.map(url => 
    Try(WS.url(url.url).get().map(x => x.statusText))
        .recover{case e: IllegalArgumentException => Future.successful(url.url + " is illegal.")}
        .recover{case t: Throwable => Future.failed(t)}
        .get
)
```

Also note that the use of `future{ .. }` is deprecated.